# Please share your experience with JavaScriptMVC, alternatives

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

I have been reading through the documentation on the [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/) framework and it looks interesting. I am wondering if anybody here has used the framework, and with what success.

So please share your experience with [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/), if you have any. If you can suggest another MVC javascript framework that is fine to.

Best regards, Egil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with JavascriptMVC. However another really famous MVC framework for Javascript is ActiveJS http://www.activerecordjs.org/ which came out about a year ago. It's by Aptana the people who make Aptana Studio and Jaxer (server side javascript). I do believe that would probably hold more merrit as Jaxer is amazing technology so I have no doubt Aptana have thought about this a lot.

I also use a jQuery project called Ajaxy which offers Controllers to Ajax requests in my own projects. http://github.com/balupton/AJAXY/

Answer (score 3):

I love JavaScriptMVC.  Of course, I am a contributor.  Many people have had success with JavaScriptMVC (a few are listed on the homepage).  I've used it on 100k lines-of-code projects  to simple pages I've made for my friend's parents.

When we give trainings on it, I can tell it requires a shift in how you think about application architecture, specifically with it's focus on Thin Server Architecture.  It also is another set of 'rules' to learn.  But the great thing is that if you and your team learn and follow these rules, it becomes really easy to maintain and fix other people's code.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with JavaScriptMVC, but here goes my two cents: My background is mostly C++/Java nonetheless I have been doing web programming for a year now, mostly actionscript, but also server side java, and javascript, css, and so on.  I've been initiated in a Javascript/DWR project recently and I'm using PureMVC, which I already use and like on my works on flex/actionscript. PureMVC is the single most popular mvc for flex/actionscript btw. It also has been ported for dozens of languages and since its conception had a language agnostic approach in mind.

You might be aware of how similar the syntaxes of actionscript 3 and javascript are, so it's really easy to jump from one thing to the other. Therefore I think that would be one point in favor for you checking PureMVC out.

Answer (score 0):

JavascriptMVC is lightweight, simple, non-obtrusive. We've had good experience with it.